# How to load Desktop view instead of mobile view in webview

Tags: android, webview

Am designing an android web app, when i run on the emulator the desktop version shows but when i run on my android device mobile view rather loads. What i want is to load the desktop view on my device

Comment: That is what a web app is for. Why do you want in desktop size on device?

Comment: The mobile version is limited that is why

Comment: Hi did you fix the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server uses  the `User-Agent` header in the HTTP request to determine if the device is mobile or desktop. You can request the website with modified `User-Agent` header so that the server will think it's desktop device.

Andorid code:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
loadUrl("www.google.com",  headers);
```

For more info:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String, java.util.Map)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_detection

And for a list of available User-Agent strings:
http://www.useragentstring.com/Firefox25.0_id_19710.php

**Edit:**

After looking again at the WebView documentation, I found this in the description of the `loadUrl` function:

> Note that if this map contains any of the headers that are set by
>   default by this WebView, such as those controlling caching, accept
>   types or the User-Agent, their values may be overriden by this
>   WebView's defaults.

Which means, you cant override `User-Agent` in the way I wrote above. After searching a bit on the internet I found this: [setUserAgentString in Android webview has no effect on HTTP header used in loadURL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308714/setuseragentstring-in-android-webview-has-no-effect-on-http-header-used-in-loadu)

And came up with this code:

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
webview.loadUrl("www.google.co.il");
```

Please try it and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: hello, i tried this and it works good on the emulator but when i use on the mobile device the mobile version still loads

Comment: After rechecking the code and importing map, it tells me Cannot instantiate the type Map<String,String>